# List<T> requires '1' type arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm in the process of going through this book

```
http://hookedonlinq.com/LINQBook.ashx
```

However when I try and implement this code

```
public class Contact
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }

    public static List SampleData()
    {
        return new List { 
            new Contact { FirstName = "Barney", LastName = "Gottshall", DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1945,10,19), Phone = "885 983 8858", Email = "bgottshall@aspiring–technology.com", State = "CA" }, 
            new Contact { FirstName = "Armando", LastName = "Valdes", DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1973,12,09), Phone = "848 553 8487", Email = "val1@aspiring–technology.com", State = "WA" }, 
            new Contact { FirstName = "Adam", LastName = "Gauwain", DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1959,10,03), Phone = "115 999 1154", Email = "adamg@aspiring–technology.com", State = "AK" }, 
            new Contact { FirstName = "Jeffery", LastName = "Deane", DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1950,12,16), Phone = "677 602 6774", Email = "jeff.deane@aspiring–technology.com", State = "CA" }, 
            new Contact { FirstName = "Collin", LastName = "Zeeman", DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1935,02,10), Phone = "603 303 6030", Email = "czeeman@aspiring–technology.com", State = "FL" }, 
            new Contact { FirstName = "Stewart", LastName = "Kagel", DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1950,02,20), Phone = "546 607 5462", Email = "kagels@aspiring–technology.com", State = "WA" }, 
            new Contact { FirstName = "Chance", LastName = "Lard", DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1951,10,21), Phone = "278 918 2789", Email = "lard@aspiring–technology.com", State = "WA" }, 
            new Contact { FirstName = "Blaine", LastName = "Reifsteck", DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1946,05,18), Phone = "715 920 7157", Email = "blaine@aspiring–technology.com", State = "TX" }, 
            new Contact { FirstName = "Mack", LastName = "Kamph", DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1977,09,17), Phone = "364 202 3644", Email = "mack.kamph@aspiring–technology.com", State = "TX" }, 
            new Contact { FirstName = "Ariel", LastName = "Hazelgrove", DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1922,05,23), Phone = "165 737 1656", Email = "arielh@aspiring–technology.com", State = "OR" } };
    }
}
```

I get the error System.Collections.Generic.List requires '1' type arguments I understand that the List needs to be defined as eg

```
List<string>
```

or

```
List<int>
```

but can't work out what the Lists should be. Can anyone help?

thanks

Comment: I think you gotta specify the type of list..

Comment: take a look at my answer

Comment: As a side note: looking at the source HTML of the linked book's pages, you can see that it does specify `List<Contact>`, but the `<` and `>` haven't been HTML encoded correctly and so it's not displaying in a browser. Seems like quite an oversight for a programming book! Also might be worth contacting the author...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static List<Contact> SampleData()
```

...

```
return new List<Contact> { ....
```

...because the objects you're putting into the list are `Contact` s

An easy way to think about generics is by using the word "of", e.g. `List<Contact>` is the same as saying "A list of contacts"

Comment: and `public static List<Contact> SampleData()`

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to specify the type of list.

```
  public static List<Contact> SampleData()
    {
        return new List<Contact> { 
            new Contact { FirstName = "Barney", LastName = "Gottshall", DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1945,10,19), Phone = "885 983 8858", Email = "bgottshall@aspiring–technology.com", State = "CA" }, 
            new Contact { FirstName = "Armando", LastName = "Valdes", DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1973,12,09), Phone = "848 553 8487", Email = "val1@aspiring–technology.com", State = "WA" }, 
            new Contact { FirstName = "Adam", LastName = "Gauwain", DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1959,10,03), Phone = "115 999 1154", Email = "adamg@aspiring–technology.com", State = "AK" }, 
            new Contact { FirstName = "Jeffery", LastName = "Deane", DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1950,12,16), Phone = "677 602 6774", Email = "jeff.deane@aspiring–technology.com", State = "CA" }, 
            new Contact { FirstName = "Collin", LastName = "Zeeman", DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1935,02,10), Phone = "603 303 6030", Email = "czeeman@aspiring–technology.com", State = "FL" }, 
            new Contact { FirstName = "Stewart", LastName = "Kagel", DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1950,02,20), Phone = "546 607 5462", Email = "kagels@aspiring–technology.com", State = "WA" }, 
            new Contact { FirstName = "Chance", LastName = "Lard", DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1951,10,21), Phone = "278 918 2789", Email = "lard@aspiring–technology.com", State = "WA" }, 
            new Contact { FirstName = "Blaine", LastName = "Reifsteck", DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1946,05,18), Phone = "715 920 7157", Email = "blaine@aspiring–technology.com", State = "TX" }, 
            new Contact { FirstName = "Mack", LastName = "Kamph", DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1977,09,17), Phone = "364 202 3644", Email = "mack.kamph@aspiring–technology.com", State = "TX" }, 
            new Contact { FirstName = "Ariel", LastName = "Hazelgrove", DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1922,05,23), Phone = "165 737 1656", Email = "arielh@aspiring–technology.com", State = "OR" } };
    }
```